# Convert Complex array to simple one (for CSV)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert my complex array to simpler one for exporting that converted simpler array to the `CSV` file.

Currently my array structure is like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
      [_source] => Array
      (
        [block] => Array
        (
          [0] => Kurud
        )
        [district] => Array
        (
          [0] => Dhamtari
        )
        [state] => Array
        (
           [0] => Chhattisgarh
        )
      )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
      [_source] => Array
      (
         [block] => Array
         (
            [0] => North-Bangeluru
         )
         [district] => Array
         (
             [0] => Bangalore
         )
         [state] => Array
         (
             [0] => Karnataka
         )
       )
    )
)
```

and I want to convert above array to the below given format:

```
array(
  array("block", "district", "state"),
  array("Kurud","Dhamtari","Chhattisgarh"),
  array("North-Bangeluru","Bangalore","Karnataka")
)
```

So keys will be the first element and then each element with his data.

This is what I tried:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
 if (is_array($value)) { 
   $result = array_merge($result); 
 } 
 else { 
   $result[$key] = $value; 
 } 
} 
print_r(result);
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: _“I have done like this”_ - and …? You forgot to give us an actual problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr[0]["_source"]);
$res[] = $keys;
foreach($arr as $e) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach($keys as $k)
        $temp[] = $e["_source"][$k][0];
    $res[] = $temp;
}
```

Reference: [array-keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/lsIS4)

Comment: @MukundaBhatta - missed a `[0]` - edited. Also added live example